# Bootstrap carousel indicators cycle but don't link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel_helper.rb file that should allow me to drop a carousel into a View with a single call to a `<%= carousel_for(images) %>`  function. (taken from https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-helper-bootstrap-carousel)

```
module CarouselHelper
  def carousel_for(images)
    Carousel.new(self, images).html
  end

  class Carousel
    def initialize(view, images)
      @view, @images = view, images
      @uid = SecureRandom.hex(6)
    end

    def html
      content = safe_join([indicators, slides, controls])
      content_tag(:div, content, id: uid, class: 'carousel slide', data_ride: 'carousel')
    end

    private

    attr_accessor :view, :images, :uid
    delegate :link_to, :content_tag, :image_tag, :safe_join, to: :view

    def indicators
      items = images.count.times.map { |index| indicator_tag(index) }
      content_tag(:ol, safe_join(items), class: 'carousel-indicators')
    end

    def indicator_tag(index)
      options = {
        class: (index.zero? ? 'active' : ''),
        data: { 
          target: uid, 
          slide_to: index
        }
      }

      content_tag(:li, '', options)
    end

    def slides
      items = images.map.with_index { |image, index| slide_tag(image, index.zero?) }
      content_tag(:div, safe_join(items), class: 'carousel-inner')
    end

    def slide_tag(image, is_active)
      options = {
        class: (is_active ? 'item active' : 'item'),
      }

      content_tag(:div, image_tag(image), options)
    end

    def controls
      safe_join([control_tag('left'), control_tag('right')])
    end

    def control_tag(direction)
      options = {
        class: "#{direction} carousel-control",
        data: { slide: direction == 'left' ? 'prev' : 'next' }
      }

      icon = content_tag(:i, '', class: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-#{direction}")
      control = link_to(icon, "##{uid}", options)
    end
  end
end
```

The HTML this produces seems to match exactly what I find in basic examples from the bootstrap website and other sources.  Everything works smoothly except the indicators do not link to any slides. They cycle through with the carousel though.  If I add the carousel using plain HTML in the View, the indicators work fine.  Any ideas why this behavior would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue :-) Since nobody answered yet and it took me a bit to figure out, here's the fix that worked for me.

The problem in carousel-indicators seems to be that we need to pass the data-target attribute a selector which means the ID must be prefixed with #

So basically just change this

```
def indicator_tag(index)
  options = {
    class: (index.zero? ? 'active' : ''),
    data: { 
      target: uid, 
      slide_to: index
    }
  }
```

to this

```
def indicator_tag(index)
  options = {
    class: (index.zero? ? 'active' : ''),
    data: {
      target: "##{uid}",
      slide_to: index
    }
  }
```

cheers